# Subscribers.Update is not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, unsubscribe

I'm trying to Unsubscribe some Subscribers based on the data retrieved from the Data Extension.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1");
try {

//initiate DE using it's Name  
var myDE = DataExtension.Init("UnsubscribedFromEmailClient");

//retrieve data with Lookup, Retrive() function is not working  
var rows = myDE.Rows.Lookup(["Status"],["active"]); 

//interate by DE all Rows
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var subscriberKey = rows[i].SubscriberKey;
  Write("<p>"+Stringify(subscriberKey)+"</p>");
    var email = rows[i].EmailAddress;
  Write("<p>"+Stringify(email)+"</p>");
    var subJson = {"SubscriberKey":subscriberKey, "EmailAddress":email};

//initiate Subscriber using Subscriber Key
   var subObj = Subscriber.Init(subscriberKey);
   var subLists = subObj.Lists.Retrieve();
  
  for (var j=0; j<subLists.length; j++){
   var listID = subLists[j]["List"]["ID"]; //Get the ListID for each List
         if (subLists[j]["List"]["Name"] == "All Subscribers") {
           var cLists = List.Retrieve({Property:"ID", SimpleOperator:"equals", Value:listID});
           if (cLists.length > 0){
              var uList = List.Init(cLists[0].CustomerKey);
              var subStatus = uList.Subscribers.Update(subJson,"Unsubscribed");
              Write("<p>"+Stringify(subStatus)+"</p>");
           }
         }  
  }
  
}
  
  } catch (error) {
    Write("<br>error: " + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
```

For each record I'm getting the "subStatus" value = "OK", however once I'm querying Data Views "ent._ListSubscribers" just to check the results - all the mentioned Subscribers appear with the status "active". It shouldn't be like that.

Please, tell me what is missing here..

Comment: I am guessing you are doing this in a child BU - this might be why then. That child BU might be set to have Unsubs be BU level, meaning you are unsubbing them from that BU, not the parent/enterprise level, which is why `ent._ListSubscribers` is returning no change in status.

Comment: You are right, thank you, all working fine now :)